# How to compare some_time|timeuntil with specific time interval in Django templates?

Tags: python, django

I'm making a new label on my BBS. (When an article is a relatively new one, then a label says 'this is new one' appears.)

After reading [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#timeuntil) I know `|timeunitl` returns the value from given time to now. I want to compare this value to a specific time interval such as two days or two hours. So I tired below

```
{% if article.created_at|timeuntil < 2 %}
    <span class = "label label-new">NEW</span>
{% endif %}
```

However, I can't see `<span class = "label label-new">NEW</span>` in actual page no matter how I change the value of the right side. How Can I compare this value?

My Django version is 1.11.16, and Python version is 3.6.7.

Comment: I don't remember now if it is possible, but if you used `{% with until=article.created_at|timeuntil %}` and then compared it `{% if untl.total_seconds < 7200 %}`?Alternatively, you could create own template filter returning number of hours.

Comment: Did you notice that in the code you pasted, that you are using "timeunitl" instead of "timeuntil"?

Comment: @mfrackowiak Do you mean make a custom template filter that returns total seconds?

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII I already checked that in a real code before asking this question. It's a mistake when I wrote this question.

Comment: @IMES either total seconds, or already converted to hours (/days) for better readability :) Maybe hours itself aren't that complicated, but if you had a rule e.g. for 4 days, or some other longer period of time, comparing it in template to large number of seconds won't be very clear for anyone else (or you in 6 months).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest would be if you make a custom filter to compute the difference in days/hours:

```
def day_diff(a_date):
    today = int(datetime.now().strftime("%d"))
    return a_date.day - today
```

and use it in the view as:

```
{% if article.created_at|day_diff < 2 %}
    <span class = "label label-new">NEW</span>
{% endif %}
```